# Getting a NOT.AUTHORIZED.ERROR when trying to call fedex api tracking

Tags: c#, restsharp, fedex

I am trying to connect and pull tacking data from FedEx using there API.

I have been successful in connecting to and getting a response from  https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com//oauth/token and getting the token.

When I then try to connect and get the tracking data I am getting "NOT.AUTHORIZED.ERROR" error response.

```cs
            string input = "{\r\n  \"trackingInfo\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"trackingNumberInfo\": {\r\n        \"trackingNumber\": \"794843185271\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"includeDetailedScans\": true\r\n}";

            var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/oauth/token",Method.Post);

            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecert", ParameterType.RequestBody);


            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("                         ");
            Console.WriteLine("#########################");
            Console.WriteLine("                         ");
            

            rff = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponceFromFedex>(response.Content);

            string token = rff.access_token;

            request = new RestRequest("/track/v1/trackingnumbers", Method.Post);

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token);
            request.AddHeader("X-locale", "en_US");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            request.AddParameter("application/json", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            response = client.Execute(request);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I am very new to this API stuff and have no idea what I am doing, Any help would be greatly appreciated

I should add that I have been able to make the call using PostMan, I just don't know to to translate that to C#

I have tried tweaking setting and have not been able to get a proper response

Comment: Inside your browsers developers console, go to the Network tab and look at the request and response and see what the difference is between your request via postman compared to your request via .Net. Your browser will block some pertinent information so you may have to use a tool like Fiddler to get more information.

Comment: Maybe Fedex is picky with casing. Try "Bearer"

Comment: Postman can generate c# RestClient calls. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @Ralf I have not, how does one do that?

Comment: I was final got this to work, I added 
client.AddDefaultQueryParameter("access_token", token); where the token is the token return by the oauth/token call.

Answer (score -1):

To finaly get this to work I had to add a Default Query Parameter to the client

client.AddDefaultQueryParameter("access_token", token);

Here is a full look at the code

```cs
            string input = "{\r\n  \"trackingInfo\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"trackingNumberInfo\": {\r\n        \"trackingNumber\": \"794843185271\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"includeDetailedScans\": true\r\n}";

            var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/oauth/token",Method.Post);

            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecert", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("                         ");
            Console.WriteLine("#########################");
            Console.WriteLine("                         ");
            

            rff = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponceFromFedex>(response.Content);

            string token = rff.access_token;

            request = new RestRequest("/track/v1/trackingnumbers", Method.Post);

            //Line of code that was added.
            client.AddDefaultQueryParameter("access_token", token);

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token);
            request.AddHeader("X-locale", "en_US");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            request.AddParameter("application/json", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            response = client.Execute(request);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```